# Firefox redirects localhost to the current IP of the network adapter

Tags: firefox, redirection, localhost

I have a really strange problem. If I try to access an locally running web application via localhost then my Firefox redirects me to the IP of my network adapter an removes the given port. In Internet Explorer or Chrome everything works fine and no redirect is happening. I also completely removed Firefox an reinstalled, but the problem still exists.

For example if I try to access a local tomcat via http://localhost:8080 then I will be redirected to http://192.168.0.2, which is the IP given to my network adapter

Anyone have an idea why this could happen? Also no proxy is configured...

Best regards, Chris

Comment: What IP do you get when you `ping localhost`?

Comment: Then I got the IP v6 Address for localhost "::1". As I said in other browsers everything just works fine. Only Firefox seems to facing this issue...

Comment: To get what @bfrguci was asking execute `ping -4 localhost` to force IPv4. Judging by the fact that Chrome does not redirect I have a feeling that it will report `127.0.0.1` as one would expect. If you open the Network tab of the developer tools by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + Q` and browse to the page, do the headers indicate any kind of redirect?

Comment: If I use `ping -4 localhost` then it reports `127.0.0.1`. In the developer tools I see an `301 Moved Permanent`...

Comment: As server Firefox shows me `BlueCoat-Security-Appliance`. I have McAfee installed on this pc, maybe this is the problem? But this only happens in Firefox and if I try to access `localhost`. `http://127.0.0.1:9080` is no problem..

Comment: I have the same problem. 10.11.12.13 is my machine's IP address. The redirect looks like this. ------ `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`
`Server: BlueCoat-Security-Appliance`
`Location: http://10.11.12.13`
`Connection: Close`